# Converting sets into regular expressions

Tags: regular-expressions, notation

In my book:

- The set `{abb, a, b, bba}` is said to be converted into regular expression `abb + a + b + bba`.
- The set `{01, 10}` to regular expression `01 + 10`

Does the `+`'s here represent concatenation or union?

Comment: In regular expressions, $+$ is union

Comment: There is only one true answer: looks at the definition.

Answer (score 4):

We don't quite convert a set to a regular expression. Rather, we give a regular expression for a *language* (i.e., a regular expression which defines the same language). For example, a regular expression for the language $\{01,10\}$ is $01+10$, and a regular expression for the language $\{abb,a,b,bba\}$ is $a+b+abb+bba$. There can be other regular expressions. For example, another regular expression for the second language is $a(\epsilon+bb) + b(\epsilon+ba)$.

Regarding the syntax of regular expressions, this should be explained in your book.